# Java cannot instantiate type ActionListener

Tags: java

im trying to add an ActionListener to my buttons for my calculator Im making. The problem is that Im being presented an error when I try to make an ActionListener. I tried in one class then I created a listener class just to see if that would help. Here is my code:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public abstract class Main extends JFrame implements Listener{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
//Main variables
String dis = "0";
double ans = Double.parseDouble(dis);


 //Making frames
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();

 //Buttons
 JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
 JButton sub = new JButton("-");
 JButton add = new JButton("+");
 JButton div = new JButton("÷");
 JButton mult = new JButton("*");
 JTextField text = new JTextField(dis);

 //Font
 Font bigFont = text.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 30f);
 Font butf = text.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20f);
 //Methods
 panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
 panel.add(text);
 panel.setSize(590, 100);
 text.setColumns(22);
 text.setFont(bigFont);
 text.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
 text.setEditable(false);
 enter.setForeground(Color.RED);
 sub.setForeground(Color.RED);
 div.setForeground(Color.RED);
 mult.setForeground(Color.RED);
 add.setForeground(Color.RED);
 //Buttons Methods
 enter.setBounds(470, 450, 100, 150);
 sub.setBounds(470, 350, 100, 90);
 div.setBounds(470, 250, 100, 90);
 mult.setBounds(470, 150, 100, 90);
 add.setBounds(470, 50, 100, 90);
 enter.setFont(butf);
 sub.setFont(butf);
 div.setFont(butf);
 mult.setFont(butf);
 add.setFont(butf);
 //Frame
 frame.add(div);
 frame.add(mult);
 frame.add(sub);
 frame.add(enter);
 frame.add(add);
 frame.add(panel);
 frame.setSize(600, 650);
 frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setVisible(true);


 //extra
 text.setSize(1000, 100);


 //Actions
```

}
}

```
package main;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public interface Listener extends ActionListener {
//Throwing error here 'Cant instantiate the type ActionListener'
ActionListener al = new ActionListener();
public default void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }



}
```

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: You're creating an instance of `ActionListener`, which is an `interface`, inside an interface?

Comment: You're also going to be very disapointed with the results of your layout, have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for better solutions

Answer (score 1):

To declare an ActionListener use

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //dostuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `ActionListener` is a `interface`, it can't be instantiated, without provide a concrete implementation of it's contract
- `interface`s can't contain instance fields

Simply speaking, it should look more like...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public interface Listener extends ActionListener {

    public default void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

}
```

You may also like to have a closer look at

- [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [What Is an Interface?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)
- The [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) trail

In Swing, you should make sure that your UI is only created and manipulated from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Have a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

You're also going to be very disappointed with the results of your layout, have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for better solutions

Comment: You should be declaring a class Listener, not an interface Listener

Comment: @phflack No, you don't have to, put it in your IDE and see.  You might also like to have a look at [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).  I'm not saying that what the OP has done is right, but that's what they were attempting to do based on the code they have provided ;)

Comment: Seems like the wrong way to go about it, since it's the only method in ActionListener, it would make more sense if you're trying to add functionality to it or something, but the interface is there to tell others to implement that function.  I guess you want to be able to use that to just have class Foo implements Listener and it gets the functionality without needing to do anything more?  Need to consider how much it fragments the code base.

Comment: @phflack I don't disagree, but given what the OP posted, that's what they "seemed" to be doing, didn't say that what they were doing was the right way, but I have little or no context to go on to know what is they were attempting to do.  Which is why my answer is full of links to tutorials ;)

Comment: Also, I can't get your code to compile using javac on debian, it's exactly as you have it inside Listener.java, and throws 10 errors, with a System.out.println(e); it throws 12 errors instead.  For future reference, just how is default supposed to be used?  Removing default from it fixes all of the errors

Comment: @phflack What version of Java are you using?  Did check out the link to [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) I linked in to a previous comment?

Comment: I checked out the link, and using java 1.7.0_79 for JRE and JDK, not using any IDEs but just a .java file and javac

Comment: @phflack So, default methods were introduced in Java 8

Comment: That would explain it, I thought they've been around for a bit longer than that, not sure debian has java 8 on apt-get yet though, which kind of makes me not want to use default if it's java 8+ only